# Js drag n drop img with deleting the current target image

Tags: javascript, html

I try to do a drag n drop with image where the user can drop an image that will replace the existing image at the targeted place ("zone"). Instead of replacing, it deletes the image and doesn't put the new one. I don't know what i do wrong

html code very basic one :

```
<body>
    <img id ="depart" src= "img/bookermini.png" alt="booker" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img id ="test" src= "img/bobafettmini.png" alt="boba" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <div id="zone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</body>
```

the Js code :

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
  var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
  nodeCopy.id = "newId";
  var element = document.getElementById("zone");
  while (element.firstChild) {
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
  }
  ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
}
```

here is a codepen is you want to try : https://codepen.io/minise/pen/KKzzvwa
the first drag n drop works fine but when i do a 2nd drop it just deletes it.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the current innerHTML of the zone element and append the dragged element to it

Here is the modified drop function:

```
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  const clone = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true)
  const zone = document.getElementById('zone');

  zone.innerHTML='';
  zone.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/ouvjbq6k/